# $|G: A^x \cap B^y| < |G:A| |G:B|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A,B \leq G$, and $x,y \in G$. If $|G:A| , |G:B| < \infty$, prove that
$|G: A^x \cap B^y| < |G:A| |G:B|$.

Hint: If $G$ acts on $X$ and $Y$, then $G$ acts on $X \times Y$ and $St(x,y)=St(x) \cap St(y)$.

Edit: I can solve the problem without the hint! but I asked to do it with the asked way: Group Actions and Stabilizers!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|G:A|=|G:A^x|$. So It is enough to show that

$$|G:C\cap D|\leq|G:C||G:D|$$

Set $$\phi(xC\cap D)=(xC,xD)$$

Where $\phi: L(C\cap D)\to L(C)\times L(D)$. Then It is easy to show that $\phi$ is one to one.

**Note:** $C=A^x,D=B^y$ and $L(X)$ is the left cosets of $X$ in $G$.

**With Group Action**

Let $G$ acts on $L(C)\times L(D)$ by $x.(C\cap D)=(xC,xD)$. Then $Stab(C,D)=Stab(C)\cap Stap(D)=C\cap D$. Hnece the orbit of $(C,D)$ has $|G:C\cap D|$ elemets which concludes the reslt.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I asked to solve this problem with group actions.

Comment: @user226063: I also adds the group action solıtion.

Comment: That;s the same argument worded slightly differently. $A^x$ is the stabilizer of the coset $xA$, $B^y$ is the stabilizer of $yB$, so $A^x \cap B^y = {\rm St}(xA,yB)$ and $|G:{\rm St}(xA,yB))| \le |G:{\rm St}(xA)||G:{\rm St}(yB)| = |G:A^x||G:B^y|=|G:A||G:B|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you.